# How to calculate average values of a jsonb field with Rails 4.2 and Postgresql 9.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, average, jsonb

I have a jsonb column which stores the values of multiple fields like this:

```
{a: "0.5", b: "0.9" }
```

I need to get the average "a" value from a collection of records.

If it would'n be a jsonb column then it is fairly simple like this:

```
Apples.average(:a)
```

but what is needed right now is something like this:

```
Apples.average(:my_numbers => {:a})
```

or

```
Apples.average("my_numbers['a']")
```

Whats the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL query would be:

```
SELECT avg((my_numbers->>'a')::numeric)
FROM   tbl;
```

[The Postgres operator to get the *value* for a given key in a `json` / `jsonb` column is `->>`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html).

This returns data type `text`. To calculate an average you need a numeric type. Casting to [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) since this one can deal with any numeric data.